# Postgres Return multiple row column values as string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `servers` with columns `server` and `site` as laid out below:

```
table servers:
server       site
servern1    .biz.net
servern2    .biz.net
servern3    .biz.net
```

I'm trying to get an output as a string in one line as shown below

```
servern1.biz.net:servern1;servern2.biz.net:servern2;servern3.biz.net:servern3
```

and not had much luck as my attempt below shows

```
postgres=# select array_to_string(array_agg(server),':')||site||':'||server as vals from servers group by server,site;

          vals           
-------------------------
 servern2.biz.com:servern2
 servern3.biz.com:servern3
 servern1.biz.com:servern1
(3 rows)
```

Any help/advice is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
select string_agg(server||':'||site, ';') as vals
from servers;
```

If either column could be empty or null, `concat_ws()` might be a better choice:

```
select string_agg(concat_ws(':', server, site), ';') as vals
from servers;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's ace, thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

I've just tweaked a little for the desired result as shown below

```
select string_agg(concat_ws('', server, site,':',server), ';') as vals from servers;

                                  vals                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
servern1.biz.net:servern1;servern2.biz.net:servern2;servern3.biz.net:servern3
(1 row)
```